# Ruby: nesting classes in classes same as nesting classes in modules?

Tags: ruby, oop, nested-class

In Ruby, one can declare classes like

```
class A
    class B
    end
end
```

and then instantiate the inner class like `A::B.new`.

Does `B` have some sort of special relationship with `A` (as is the case in Java) or is `A` just its namespace? In other words, is nesting a class in a class the same as nesting it in a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's essentially the same as nesting in module. Nested class does not have any kind of special relationship to the class it's nested in.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those times when you should really just fire up irb and try it.

Yes, a class can be defined within another class. Since a class's superclass is Module (i.e. Class extends Module), they can do almost everything a Module can. A notable exception is that you cannot `include` (mixin) a class.

That said, there's very little reason to actually use this design pattern. It is more likely that A and B can be considered siblings. There is no need to arbitrarily namespace until you are blue in the face. If you are more than 3 levels deep, stop and consider refactoring.

A better design pattern for this example might be:

```
module Alphabet
  class A; end
  class B; end
end
```

For something more complicated, this continues to work nicely using Mixins:

```
module Animals
  class Dog
    include Walking
  end

  module Walking
    # some methods pertaining to the ability to walk
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer anticipates well the design issues anyone interested in this question will probably have to think about, but afaict doesn't answer the question directly. I intentionally stripped my question of domain specific stuff to make it a purely technical yes/no question, but I think this is still a good answer to have in this thread.

Comment: I directly answer the question in the second sentence, and explain why. I edited my question to include a bit more background on why this feature is better left alone, though.

Comment: I already knew a class could be defined within another class. The question was whether this behaves exactly the same as a class defined within a module or whether the inner class has some special relationship with the outer class that a class in a module doesn't have. Maybe you mistook the first sentence of the question to be the question :) In any case I understand and agree with your advice.

Comment: Oh wow, I transposed the "one can" in your first sentence and read "can one declare classes like". I guess I didn't explicitly state that the relationship between A and B is the same as if A were a module, but that is the case, yes. They do have a relationship, but it isn't different from that of a class in a module, just to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and...no. A Module can't be instantiated whereas a class can, so there is a difference in nesting a class within a Module vs. using a class nested within a class.

For example: You cannot instantiate an object of Ford here (i.e. Cobra, F-150, Mustang, etc.) because you cannot instantiate a module,.

```
         `module Ford
            class Engine
              ...
            end
          end`
```

But you **can** have an instance of the class Ford as well as instances of Ford engines with using nested classes like so:

```
       `class Ford
           class Engine
             @@actions = ['list', 'find', 'add', 'quit']
             def self.actions; @@actions; end
           end

           def self.truck_exists?
             #Some more stuff here
           end
        end`
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes (and Modules) have different usages:

- Namespace: when you define a class (or module) inside another class (or module), you have to use a different notation outside the defining class to reach the inner class or module.
- Template for instances: There  modules and classes behave totally (well mostly) different.
- Inheritance: You may extend a class, so you inherit all its attributes and methods, which works for modules as well. Or you may include a module (not: a class) to add its methods (and attributes) to your scope. Ruby plays here tricks by mixin the module in the class hierarchy.

So in the context of using name spaces, they are the same. However I would all the time use modules (only), but that is more a matter of style. The best book on this topic is in my opinion "Metaprogramming Ruby" by Paolo Perrotta.

Comment: Modules and classes do not behave different except in that a class can be instantiated. *Metaprogramming Ruby* is a good book, but you might want to give it another read-through.